# Drop down sub-menu isn't working

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to html and css, and I'm trying to create a drop-down menu with sub-menus in it on a navigation bar, but I'm having the issue of my sub-menus not showing up. I've tried several methods online, but I can't seem to get it right.

Here is the CSS and HTML:

```css
.NavMenu li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.NavMenu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: Crimson;
}
.NavMenu li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
.NavMenu li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
.NavMenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.NavMenu ul ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  display: float;
}
.NavMenu li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="NavMenu">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="EngHome.html"> My Bilingual Library </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a> Find Books </a>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="Elementary.html"> Elementary </a>
          <ul>
            <li> <a href="ElemPict.html"> Picture Books </a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="ElemFict.html"> Fiction Books </a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="ElemNFict.html"> Non-Fiction Books </a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="ElemChapt.html"> Chapter Books </a> 
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li> <a href="MidSchool.html"> Middle School </a>
          <ul>
            <li> <a href="MidAdventure.html"> Adventure </a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="MidFantasy.html"> Fantasy </a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="MidNonFict.html"> Non-Fiction </a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="MidRealFict.html"> Realistic Fiction </a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="MidBiography.html"> Biography </a> 
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li> <a href="HighSchool.html"> High School </a>
          <ul>
            <li> <a href="HighAdven.html"> Adventure </a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="HighFantasy.html"> Fantasy </a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="HighThrill.html"> Thriller </a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="HighMystery.html"> Mystery </a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="HighPoetry.html"> Poetry </a> 
            </li>
            <li> <a href="Comedy.html"> Comedy </a> 
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="Favorites.html"> Favorites </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="Contact.html"> Contact </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="Howto.html"> How to </a> 
    </li>
    <li style="float:right"> <a href="SpanHome.html"> Espa&#241;ol? </a> 
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Any sort of advice to make this work would be greatly appreciated, if you believe I should just scrap it all and start over, feel free to tell me so. Thank you.
[Here is a screenshot of the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9GuH.png)

Comment: Do you have a live version of this, a jsfiddle, or just a screenshot so we can see what it looks like now?

Comment: I've put your code in a snippet so that we can see the output. It might require a little bit of tweaking to get it to display right.

Comment: I assume your question is about the sub-sub-menus under "Find Books". If that is the case, I'd recommend removing the other menus from the example, since they're not really part of the question.

Comment: Yes I am asking about the sub-sub menus under "Find Books," sorry I didn't remove the unnecessary bit

Comment: What isn't working like you expect it to?

Comment: What I mean is, you can edit your question and remove the unnecessary parts, to make a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It wasnt showing the sub menus when hovering over the items in the drop-down menu, if that makes any sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coluld you please try this code. http://codepen.io/nehemc/pen/yJbRga

```
<style>
.NavMenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: Crimson;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.NavMenu li {
    float: left;
    position:relative;
}
.NavMenu li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.NavMenu li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
.NavMenu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left:0;
    z-index:999;
}
.NavMenu ul ul li {
    float:none;
}
.NavMenu ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    display: float;
}
.NavMenu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
</style>
<nav class="NavMenu">
<ul>
  <li> <a href="EngHome.html"> My Bilingual Library </a> </li>
  <li> <a> Find Books </a>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href= "Elementary.html"> Elementary </a>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href= "ElemPict.html"> Picture Books </a> </li>
          <li> <a href= "ElemFict.html"> Fiction Books </a> </li>
          <li> <a href= "ElemNFict.html"> Non-Fiction Books </a> </li>
          <li> <a href= "ElemChapt.html"> Chapter Books </a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href= "MidSchool.html"> Middle School </a>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href= "MidAdventure.html"> Adventure </a> </li>
          <li> <a href= "MidFantasy.html"> Fantasy </a> </li>
          <li> <a href= "MidNonFict.html"> Non-Fiction </a> </li>
          <li> <a href= "MidRealFict.html"> Realistic Fiction </a> </li>
          <li> <a href= "MidBiography.html"> Biography </a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href= "HighSchool.html"> High School </a>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href= "HighAdven.html"> Adventure </a> </li>
          <li> <a href= "HighFantasy.html"> Fantasy </a> </li>
          <li> <a href= "HighThrill.html"> Thriller </a> </li>
          <li> <a href= "HighMystery.html"> Mystery </a> </li>
          <li> <a href= "HighPoetry.html"> Poetry </a> </li>
          <li> <a href= "Comedy.html"> Comedy </a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="Favorites.html"> Favorites </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="Contact.html"> Contact </a> </li>
  <li> <a href="Howto.html"> How to </a> </li>
  <li style= "float:right"> <a href="SpanHome.html"> Espa&#241;ol? </a> </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You should explain what you did, this way the OP can learn from your answer instead of having to ask again next time.

Comment: This worked, thank you! If you could tell me what you changed, I would be very grateful.

Comment: You have missed add "position:relative; to .NavMenu li"

Comment: Misssed this also .NavMenu ul ul { left:0; z-index:999;}

Answer (score 0):

Changing from `absolute` to `relative` here,

```
NavMenu ul ul {
    position: relative; 
    display: none;
}
```

makes your nested lists show, you will just need to mess with the styling a bit more after that so they align how you want them to